# A wrong amplitude in a plotted signal using Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have plotted a signal in Matlab, but I have no idea why it is plotting it with a wrong amplitude.
Here is the code:

```
%My signal: ()=,∙(,∙∙+). 
syms t; 
A = 0.001; %Amplitude
T = 400; %Period
f = 0.0025; %Frequency
pi = 3.14; 


%Plotting the signal
y = A*cos(0.005*pi*t+pi/4);

figure('Name','Signal y = A*cos(0.005*pi*t+pi/4)') 
ezplot(y, [-T/2, T/2]); 
title('y = A*cos(0.005*pi*t+pi/4)');
xlabel('Time'), ylabel('Amplitude');
grid on;
```

But I get a signal with a wrong value of amplitude (It plots with an amplitude of value 1 instead of 0.001):

[image]

I guess I am overlooking some mistake, but I still can't figure it out.
Could you please give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct. See the multiplying factor in the top left corner.

Comment: Sorry for my stupid question now, but you mean the syms t?

Comment: No. ×10−3 printed on left top corner of the graph.

Comment: Every amplitude value should be multiplied by ×10−3

Comment: Yes, now I see it. Thank you very much!